# c# datagridview differentiate user input from program

Tags: c#, input, datagridview

I have a C# WinForm `DataGridView`.

The program should be able to change the cells values in the `DataGridView`, but the user should not be allowed to.

I.e.: how can I differentiate whether the user or the program is editing a cell in a `DataGridView`?

So far I only found the **readonly** property (e.g. of a column). But then the program is not able to edit the column either.

I could leave the column `readonly=true` and when the program wants to change a cell value, make `readonly=false`, change value, `readonly=true`...but this solution seems very bad to me, especially if a column needs constant update from the program (e.g. a financial price data stream), but i don't want the user to change the price (even though it would be overwritten soon by the program, which might or might not happen soon).

Thanks,
Imran

Answer (score 1):

You mean this?

```
dataGridView1.EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditProgrammatically;
```

Comment: oh man, i think i just found it...

my datagridview was bound to a datatable and making a datatable column readonly does not allow nor the user nor the program to change a cell value.

but making the datagridview column itself readonly will forbid user input but allow the program to change the value...

sorry for asking, should have tried 10 minutes more...

Comment: (wasnt allowed to answer my own question (new user))

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 'Enabled' property of the DataGridView to enable user input of the entire data grid.

Comment: I didn't clarify, but I meant that certain columns should have the desired property, certain columns should be completely open to editing also by the user